# Can @Bean @Configuration be inherited?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

It is possible in spring to inherit from an abstract class, and let the implementation automatically create an instance of any `@Bean` annotated method?

```
Example:
abstract class BaseConfig {
    @Bean
    public Car car() {
            //very complex initialize routine for a car
        Car car = new Car();
        car.setmanufacture(getManufacture());
            System.out.println("complex car created");
        return car;
    }

    abstract Manufacture getManufacture();
}

@Configuration
CustomManu1 extends BaseConfig {
    Manufacture getManufacture() {
        //return custom manufacture
    }
}

@Configuration
CustomManu2 extends BaseConfig {
    Manufacture getManufacture() {
        //return custom manufacture
    }
}


@Configuration
@Import({CustomManu1.class, CustomManu2.class})
public class AppConfig {
}
```

Is that possible to inherit the `@Bean` and let spring create 2 Beans of type `Car` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, public methods are inherited, so `CustomManu1` and `CustomManu2` will inherit the `@Bean` annotated method `car()`.

> and let spring create 2 Beans of type Car here?

This depends how you load your `@Configuration` classes.

Comment: Well, how would I have to load my `@Configuration` classes for having 2 beans?

Comment: @membersound Load them both.

Comment: Sounds a bit confusing, same application context having 2 beans of same type. How to refer separately? Will application context not just have one bean of this type

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj Well, technically, yes. If both `@Configuration` classes are loaded by the  same `ApplicationContext`, since they have the same name, there will only be one bean definition and therefore only one bean.

Comment: Loading both configurations I already tried. Modified the example above. The bean is only created a single time, not 2 times!

Comment: @membersound Yeah, see my latest comment. So, no. With a single `ApplicationContext`, you cannot do it.

Comment: Set scope to prototype for Car and try to get the bean using application context.getBean. Each call to this function should return a new instance.

Comment: Ok that would be an option. But in my application I tend to use this as provider of different webservice configurations with different credentials. But I'd like to reuse these as configuration will be quite heavy. So I'll probably have to implement each method explicit with `@Bean`.